# Echo something while piping stdout

Tags: bash, pipe, echo

I know how to pipe stdout:

```
./myScript | grep 'important'
```

Example output of the above command:

```
Very important output.
Only important stuff here.
```

But while `grep`ing I would also like to `echo` something each line so it looks like this:

```
1) Very important output.
2) Only important stuff here.
```

How can I do that?

Edit: Apparently, I haven't specified well enough what I want to do. Numbering of lines is just an example, I want to know in general how to add text (any text, including variables and whatnot) to pipe output. I see one can achieve that using `awk '{print $0}'` where `$0` is the solution I'm looking for.

Are there any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: This is not related to programming in any way whatsoever, but try `grep -n 'important'`.

Comment: I am doing mind reading here. For messages, you better use `stderr` to inform progress of the script. This will not interfere with the `stdout` you are piping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will number the hits from 0

```
./myScript | grep 'important' | awk '{printf("%d) %s\n", NR, $0)}'

1) Very important output.
2) Only important stuff here.
```

This will give you the line number of the hit

```
./myScript | grep -n 'important'

3:Very important output.
47:Only important stuff here.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want line numbers on the new output running from 1..n where n is number of lines in the new output:

```
./myScript | awk '/important/{printf("%d) %s\n", ++i, $0)}'
#                  ^ Grep part                     ^ Number starting at 1
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with a `while` loop is not suited for large files, so you should only use this solution when you do not have a lot `important` stuff:

```
i=0
while read -r line; do
   ((i++))
   printf "(%s) Look out: %s" $i "${line}"
done < <(./myScript | grep 'important')
```